# why layer of dimension 1 is outputting image of size n

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, kernel

I am studying a model where landmarks from an image are calculated. The work comes from [Convolutional Experts Constrained Local Model for 3D Facial Landmark Detection](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017_workshops/papers/w36/Zadeh_Convolutional_Experts_Constrained_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf).

[image]

I need to confirm why the convolutional layer of 200 *1*1 is outputting 200 by n~ *n~. my guess is that it is 200 * n~ *n~ with kernel size 1, but I need to be sure.

Can someone please guide.

Thanks in advance
[1]: https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017_workshops/papers/w36/Zadeh_Convolutional_Experts_Constrained_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi9Nq.png
[3]: [How does Sigmoid activation work in multi-class classification problems](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39264/how-does-sigmoid-activation-work-in-multi-class-classification-problems)

Comment: Do you mean "the convolutional layer of 200 x 1 x 1 is outputting 100 x 1 x 1"?

Comment: Below the convolution block, you can see the output as 200 x n x n. That is the output shape